# Summing Sales Data Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm just starting out with SQL, I have been playing around with simple select queries and grouping data, now I want to pull some actually useful data out of our database for analysis.  The data is organized as follows:

Access 2010 Database
I didn't set it up, I know it isn't set up as it should be

I can't change data, only poll

-Customers are kept in one table

-Closed orders are kept in another table (each line item is listed with invoice #, date closed, Customer ID as well as other info)

-Archived closed orders table keep sales records that are a year + old (table is laid out exactly the same as Closed order table)

I want to start with a simple query, list all the customers from a certain branch and their past year totals.  Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.Company, CUSTOMERS.[Ship City], (SELECT SUM (CLOSEDORDERS.Quant*CLOSEDORDERS.SellPrice) FROM CLOSEDORDERS WHERE CUSTOMERS.ID = CLOSEDORDERS.CustID) AS LifeTotal

FROM CUSTOMERS, CLOSEDORDERS

WHERE CUSTOMERS.Branch=33;
```

When I run the query, it asks me to enter a parameter value for CLOSEDORDERS.Quant.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably spelling the field name wrong?

Comment: You were right, I had the table open and it showed "CustID" and "Quant", but when I opened it so I could see the values of the field, they were actually called "Quantity" and "CustomerID".  Why would the tables truncate the names like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for with an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.Company, 
       CUSTOMERS.[Ship City],
       SUM(CLOSEDORDERS.Quant*CLOSEDORDERS.SellPrice) AS LifeTotal
FROM CUSTOMERS 
    LEFT JOIN CLOSEDORDERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = CLOSEDORDERS.CustID
WHERE CUSTOMERS.Branch=33
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.Company, 
       CUSTOMERS.[Ship City]
```

If you only want to return matching results from both tables, then use a standard `INNER JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: After fixing the reference link to the correct column name (see above comment), this work beautifully.  Thank you!

Comment: Could I ask a knock on question?  What if I want to sum the actual life time totals including the archived closed orders?  The table is called ARCHIVEDCLOSEDSALES and the columns are set up just like the CLOSEDORDERS table.